# yocto SDK krogoth cmake FindBoost not found

Tags: sdk, cmake, yocto

I am trying to find the boost libraries (cmake) inside the Yocto SDK with extended environment on krogoth.

The default cmake Find_

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
```

The standard error message

`Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
 Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)`

The following is a snippet from my conf/local.conf

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost-dev"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " kernel-devsrc"

MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS += "kernel-module-hello"
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTO_lOAD += "hello-md"

LCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = "${SDK_EXTRA_TOOLS}" 
SDK_EXTRA_TOOLS = " nativesdk-cmake
```

I am using the native cmake

`auke@xenialxerus:~/workspace/beaglebone-dev/build$ which cmake
/home/auke/workspace/beaglebone-dev/poky-sdk/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/`

since I:

```
source environment-setup-cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

looking for the usual headers in:

```
find ./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/include/boost/
..
/tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/include/boost/vmd/list/to_seq.hpp
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/include/boost/vmd/list/to_tuple.hpp
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/include/boost/vmd/to_list.hpp
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/include/boost/vmd/empty.hpp
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/include/boost/vmd/is_list.hpp
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/include/boost/vmd/size.hpp
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/include/boost/vmd/get_type.hpp
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/include/boost/vmd/assert_is_identifier.hpp
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/include/boost/vmd/is_number.hpp
..
```

just like the binaries:

```
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.a
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.60.0
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.a
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.a
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_date_time.a
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.a
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_graph-mt.a
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_regex.so
./tmp/sysroots/beaglebone/usr/lib/libboost_wserialization.so.1
```

Is there something that i might have overlooked?

regards Auke

Comment: I used bitbake core-image-minimal -c populate_sdk_ext to generate the SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 
`bitbake -c populate_sdk <image_name>` to generate the SDK based on your image;

> As an alternative to locating and downloading a toolchain installer,
>   you can build the toolchain installer one of two ways if you have a
>   Build Directory:
>
> *Use bitbake meta-toolchain. This method requires you to still install
>   the target sysroot by installing and extracting it separately. For
>   information on how to install the sysroot, see the "Extracting the
>   Root Filesystem" section.
>
> *Use bitbake  -c populate_sdk. This method has significant
>   advantages over the previous method because it results in a toolchain
>   installer that contains the sysroot that matches your target root
>   filesystem.

Also, using the variable `TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK` to add more packages.
http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html

> This variable lists packages the OpenEmbedded build system uses when
>   building an SDK, which contains a cross-development environment. The
>   packages specified by this variable are part of the toolchain set that
>   runs on the SDKMACHINE, and each package should usually have the
>   prefix "nativesdk-". When building an SDK using bitbake -c
>   populate_sdk , a default list of packages is set in this
>   variable, but you can add additional packages to the list.

e.g.

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += “nativesdk-libqt5core-dev”
```

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you for your reply. The issue I now have is that it finds the libraries inside the sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include folder, instead of the tmp/sysroots/beaglebone. I assumed wrongly that the environment-settings would configure this for me. Could you elaborate on my misconception of the sdk?

Comment: Charles answer worked for the SDK and not for the eSDK. I saw some mistakes / perhaps bugs and have filed a bug report.